# Should one-to-one associations populate both sides?

Tags: node.js, model, sails.js, waterline

I have two models (user & agent). I then create a user and an agent. I am expecting to see the association when using the blueprint routes for BOTH /user and /agent. I am only seeing the user model is associated with an agent via the /agent blueprint. The /user blueprint does not have any reference/association to an Agent.

The issue presents itself when I am trying to access the Agent via A userId with the following command:

```
User.findOne(req.body.userId).populate('agent').exec(function(err, agent)
```

"agent" is in fact the user information...not the agent.

Here are my models:

**User:**

```
attributes: {
  agent: {
    model: 'agent',
    via: 'owner'
  }
}
```

**Agent:**

```
attributes: {
  owner: {
    model: 'user'
  }
}
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sails does not fully support one-to-one model associations--you have to set the "foreign key" on both sides.  See https://stackoverflow.com/a/27752329/345484 for more information.  I'm tempted to just close this question as a duplicate of that one, but the setup is slightly different.

Answer (score 1):

You have understood the `populate` wrong. `populate()` doesn't replace last call with new information. It takes attribute from model (that you specify in `populate('attribute')`) and replace id of that attribute in your model with another model information looked up by its id.

Let's dive into example.

You have `User` and `Agent` model.

```
// api/models/User.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    agent: {
      model: 'Agent',
      via: 'owner'
    }
  }
};

// api/models/Agent.js
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    owner: {
      model: 'User',
      via: 'agent'
    }
  }
};
```

You are calling `User.findOne(userId).populate('agent').exec(function(err, user) {}` and expect to get only `agent` as I understood. Wrong. It returns `User` model with `Agent` model as an attributes of `User` model.

```
// api/controllers/AnyController.js
module.exports = {
  index: function(req, res) {
    User
      .findOne(req.param('userId'))
      .populate('agent')
      .then(function(user) {
        console.log(user); // User information
        console.log(user.agent); // Agent information for that user
        return user;
      })
      .then(res.ok)
      .catch(res.negotiate);
  }
};
```

You can read about population more here - http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

Comment: I don't think this is quite the issue that OP is facing--it sounds more like a misunderstanding of one-to-one associations support in Sails.

Comment: @sgress454 I didn't know. Every time when I'm setting up one-to-one association everything works as expected.